# .WAV audio file converstion issue with oggenc

Tags: audio, converters, wav, ogg, oggenc

I have a problem converting `WAV` files to `OGG` using `oggenc`. I am always getting this exception

```
Warning: INVALID format chunk in wav header.
 Trying to read anyway (may not work)...
ERROR: Wav file is unsupported type (must be standard PCM
 or type 3 floating point PCM)
ERROR: Input file "x.wav" is not a supported format
```

I have installed all the dependencies like `libflac`, `vorbis-tools`, `libvorbis`.

This problem is heppening in one of my production servers. It works fine with the same setup in local and few other systems. I have downloaded the same wav file from production and tried it in local, it works just fine.

This is the `file` meta information of the wav file

```
>>file x.wav
x.wav: RIFF (little-endian) data, WAVE audio, stereo 48000 Hz
```

All my wav files are generated  from `mpg321` from the `MP3` source. This is the entire script

```
for f in $(find -name "*.mp3"); 
 do  
     mpg321 $f -w - | oggenc -q 5 -o "${f%.*}".ogg -;
 done;
```

From the message i understand that either

1. file is corrupted. or
2. wav codec is missing

Since the same file works without any problem in other systems, i am sure the file is a valid one. So it should be the second one.

Can someone help me out, how to check if all the dependencies for oggenc are installed correctly?

any hint would be really appreciated.

**Update**:

The above script doesnt generate wav files, it passes the generated wav audio stream to oggenc. To test the wav file in different systems, i have used these commands

```
 >> mpg321 -w x.wav 0b549a8241.mp3
 >> oggenc -q 5 -o x.ogg x.wav
```

In both methods, am getting the same error

Comment: I do not see how wav files (files, not STDOUT) are generated. I see how mp3s are converted to ogg.

Comment: @Andrey, You are right. In the script am passing the STDOUT to the oggenc. Not the file. To test that in different systems i created a wave file using `mpg321 -w x.wav 0b549a8241.mp3` In both the ways, i am getting the same error. pls check the update

Comment: Probably a mpg321's fresh bug. Take a look at: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mpg321/+bug/1178725 Try this `ffmpeg -i 1.mp3 1.wav`

Comment: Does mpg321 produce a header at all? Can you check it with a HEX editor?

Comment: If no header in a file, try `oggenc -r -R 48000 -q 5 -o x.ogg x.wav`

Comment: @AndreyVolk, seems like the same bug. i ll try with HEX editor and let you know

Comment: Andre, you saved my day. 'oggenc -r -R 48000 -q 5 -o x.ogg x.wav' this command works fine. How does changing the raw rate fixes the issue. And add this as a answer. i ll accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mpg321` does not probably produce wav headers when outputs to a standard output.

As I can see, you work with `48000` `stereo`.
`oggenc` tool uses `44100` `stereo` by default.
So `-r -R 48000` must be used:

```
oggenc -r -R 48000 -q 5 -o x.ogg x.wav
```